# Set time part of datetime variable to 18:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to set datetime variable to two days from now but it's time part must be 18:00.

For example if i call `getdate()` now i'll get `2010-05-17 13:18:07.260`. I need to set it to `2010-05-19 18:00:00.000`.

Does anybody have a good snippet for that or any ideas how to do it right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, 24 * 2 + 18, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

This truncates the current date and adds 2 days and 18 hours to it `(24 * 2 + 18)`.

A possible variation:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -2, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Comment: This feels hacky to me. I know T-SQL isn't as robust as C# but this is very difficult for me to read. I prefer the answer that adds the pieces we want back one at at time, or the answer that "floors" the date to remove the time, as both of these are easier to understand and therefore easier to maintain.

Comment: you should never assume that a day has 24 hours. There are days when daylight saving period is beginning/ending and a day can have 23 to 25 hours actually

Answer (score 5):

I had to do something similar, create a procedure to run from a certain time the previous day to a certain time on the current day 
This is what I did to set the start date to 16:30 on the previous day, basically subtract the parts you don't want to get them back to 0 then add the value that you want it to be.

```
-- Set Start Date to previous day and set start time to 16:30.00.000

SET @StartDate = GetDate()
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(dd,- 1, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(hh,- (DatePart(hh,@StartDate))+16, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(mi,- (DatePart(mi,@StartDate))+30, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(ss,- (DatePart(ss,@StartDate)), @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(ms,- (DatePart(ms,@StartDate)), @StartDate)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I prefer this answer to the one using DATEDIFF because as a developer, it is just hard to read and understand what is happening with the DATEDIFF.  Maintaining the code in this answer will be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select DateAdd(hour, 18, DateAdd(day, 2, cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float))as datetime)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is...

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 18, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()+2))) [6pm Today]
```

It probably looks pretty complicated, but believe me when I say it looks a lot worse than it really is.

To explain each function call as a sequence of steps for the query above is as follows:

1. `GETDATE()`: Gets the current date and time as a `DATETIME` value.
2. `+2`: Add two days, since each whole number in DATETIME calulations represents a day, with fractions representing fractions of a day.
3. `CONVERT(DATE,@REF)`: Convert to date format (to remove the time element)
4. `CONVERT(DATETIME,@REF)`: Convert back to DateTime (Time element defaults to midnight 00:00)
5. `DATEADD(HOUR,@NUM,@REF)`: Add 12 + 6 = 18 hours to get 6 in the afternoon

Notes:

- Change `@MyDate` to reflect the name of your own variable, bearing in mind that variables have a `@` prefix.
- Years may be added by wrapping the query between the `=` and the `[6pm Today]` in a `DATEADD(YEAR,@NUM,@REF)` function.
- Months may be added by wrapping the query between the `=` and the `[6pm Today]` in a `DATEADD(MONTH,@NUM,@REF)` function.
- Minutes may be added by wrapping the query between the `=` and the `[6pm Today]` in a `DATEADD(MINUTE,@NUM,@REF)` function.
- Seconds may be added by wrapping the query between the `=` and the `[6pm Today]` in a `DATEADD(SECOND,@NUM,@REF)` function.
- Milliseconds may be added by wrapping the query between the `=` and the `[6pm Today]` in a `DATEADD(MILLISECOND,@NUM,@REF)` function.
- I personally avoid `DATEDIFF` function, because it returns a 32bit int, which overflows often since the `DateTime` value type is stored internally as a 64bit value and represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian calendar.
- I use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST` since `CAST` calls the `CONVERT` function. It probably makes barely any difference to execution time, but if it does then it makes sense to call `CONVERT` directly.
- The white-space in the queries is mostly optional.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please say something about why this works and/or how this is different from the OP code.

Comment: Looking much better. I would be good if this could be in ANSI standard SQL. Perhaps `CAST()` instead of `CONVERT()`. See also https://teamsql.io/blog/?p=1455 and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Functions_and_expressions/Date_and_time_functions

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but still a useful example:

```
declare 
     @dt   datetime = getutcdate()
    ,@hour tinyint  = 18;

select
     @dt                                                            as dt
    ,DATEPART(hour, @dt)                                            as hour_of_day
    ,DATEADD(hour, -1*DATEPART(hour, @dt), @dt)                     as hour_00_of_day
    ,DATEADD(hour, -1*DATEPART(hour, @dt), 
     DATEADD(minute, -1*DATEPART(minute, @dt), 
     DATEADD(second, -1*DATEPART(second, @dt), 
     DATEADD(millisecond, -1*DATEPART(millisecond, @dt), @dt))))    as beginning_of_day
    ,DATEADD(hour, @hour,
         DATEADD(hour, -1*DATEPART(hour, @dt), 
         DATEADD(minute, -1*DATEPART(minute, @dt), 
         DATEADD(second, -1*DATEPART(second, @dt), 
         DATEADD(millisecond, -1*DATEPART(millisecond, @dt), @dt))))
    )                                                               as hour_18_of_day
```

And generally as a function:

```
-- =============================================
-- Description: Set datetime part (NULL to keep as is)
-- =============================================
-- SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS DT, [dbo].[udf_datetime_SET_DATE_TIME_PART] (GETUTCDATE(), 1985, 11, 19, 12, 01, 02, 0)
-- SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS DT, [dbo].[udf_datetime_SET_DATE_TIME_PART] (GETUTCDATE(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 12, NULL, NULL, NULL)
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_datetime_SET_DATE_TIME_PART]
(
     @dt            DATETIME
    ,@YEAR          INT  = NULL
    ,@MONTH         INT  = NULL
    ,@DAY_OF_MONTH  INT  = NULL
    ,@HOUR          INT  = NULL
    ,@MINUTE        INT  = NULL
    ,@SECOND        INT  = NULL
    ,@MILLISECOND   INT  = NULL
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    IF @dt IS NULL
        RETURN @dt

    SET @dt = IIF(@YEAR IS NULL
                ,@dt
                ,DATEADD(year,  -1*DATEPART(year,       @dt) + @YEAR, @dt)
        )
    SET @dt = IIF(@MONTH IS NULL
                ,@dt
                ,DATEADD(month, -1*DATEPART(month,      @dt) + @MONTH, @dt)
        )
    SET @dt = IIF(@DAY_OF_MONTH IS NULL
                ,@dt
                ,DATEADD(day,   -1*DATEPART(day,        @dt) + @DAY_OF_MONTH, @dt)
        )
    SET @dt = IIF(@HOUR IS NULL
                ,@dt
                ,DATEADD(hour,  -1*DATEPART(hour,       @dt) + @HOUR, @dt)
        )
    SET @dt = IIF(@MINUTE IS NULL
                ,@dt
                ,DATEADD(minute,    -1*DATEPART(minute,     @dt) + @MINUTE, @dt)
        )
    SET @dt = IIF(@SECOND IS NULL
                ,@dt
                ,DATEADD(second,    -1*DATEPART(second,     @dt) + @SECOND, @dt)
        )
    SET @dt = IIF(@MILLISECOND IS NULL
                ,@dt
                ,DATEADD(millisecond,   -1*DATEPART(millisecond,        @dt) + @MILLISECOND, @dt)
        )

    RETURN @dt
END
```

Comment: Handy function fn_datetime_SET_DATE_TIME_PART, thanks!