# Modify date NOW()

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to set a date to another date.

For example. With NOW() I have 2011-07-14 08:35:00

I want to modify this date to 2011-07-12 00:00:00

So I remove 1 day and I set to 00:00 am.

I have already seen this link -> [Set time part of datetime variable to 18:00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847851/set-time-part-of-datetime-variable-to-1800), but it doesn't work for me. Indeed, I compare :

**NOW()** with DATEADD(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -2, **THE_DATE_IN_MY_BASE**), 0)) and I have an SQL syntax error.

Comment: I compare NOW with DATEADD(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -2, THE_DATE_IN_MY_BASE), 0)) and I have an SQL syntax error

Comment: Please edit your question to post what you've tried along with the error message you're getting.

Comment: If you know the value to assign, why not just assign it?  Why do you need to manipulate the current time to get there?

Answer (score 1):

`now()` returns a datetime value, so hh:mm:ss will be part of it. Sounds more like you want a simple date, so use `curdate()` instead:

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: if you stuff a date into a datetime field, mysql fills in the time as 00:00:00